# How do I convert this if/else statement into idiomatic JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to write more idiomatic JavaScript. I've heard from several experts (like Douglas Crockford) that it's a best practice to avoid switch/case and complex if/else statements as much as possible, using objects and functions instead.

I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite this if/else block using objects and functions:

```
function testString(input){
    if (input.match(/\.$/)){
        return 'This string ends in a period.';
    } else if (input.match(/!$/)){
        return 'This string ends in an exclamation point.';
    } else {
        return 'This string has some other ending.';
    }
}
```

Now, I know you can replace an if/else with an object:

```
let response = {
    'Now, it\'s a good time.':'This sentence ends in a period.',
    'What up!':'This sentence ends in an exclamation point.'
};

return response[input];
```

The problem I'm having is that I only know how to use this structure with literals. How do I do a regular expression match on the left-hand side (key) of a key-value pair?

This doesn't work:

```
let response = {
    input.match(/\.$/):'This sentence ends in a period.',
    input.match(/!$/):'This sentence ends in an exclamation point.'
};

return response[input];
```

It gives me an error:

```
Unexpected token, expected ","
```

Comment: "as much as possible" but in this case it's entirely reasonable to stick with the `if..else if...` structure. It's much more obvious what the code is doing, than if you were to do some shenanigans with an object...

Comment: Then again if it's just for testing the last character of a string, `let response = {".":"Period","!":"Exclamation"}; return response[input.slice(-1)] || "Something else";`

Comment: you could omit `else` and go on with `if`, because you `return`.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a lookup table (pattern to response):

```
 const responses = [
  { pattern: /\.$/, response: "This sentence ends in a period", },
  //...
  { pattern: /.*/, response: "Nothing special", }
];

return responses.find(it => input.match(it.pattern)).response;
```

But to be honest: That is too much effort put into a few lines of code, rather focus on the big picture. Wether you use an if/else here or the solution above doesnt really matter.

Comment: Careful! this would throw a typerror when no pattern matches. In this case the `.*` exists, but if not `find` could return `undefined` and `undefined.response` throws.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't count those three cases as "*complex if/else statements*", that code is fine. If you get more of them, you could use a lookup table though:

```
function testString(input){
    const endings = {
        '.': 'ends in a period.',
        '!': 'ends in an exclamation point.';
    };
    const last = input.slice(-1);
    return 'This string ' + (last in endings ? endings[last] : 'has some other ending.');
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's probably going to be a lot more complex once I'm done with it. As somebody else pointed out, though, since it's returning, there doesn't have to be any elses.